# Dependency Injection with variable class parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, dependency-injection

I have been trying Angular 2 framework. I have an API that will return json with variable parameters, i.e. in some cases it will return `{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}`, in some cases it will return `{'c': 'c', 'd': 'd'}`. The data is shown in a child component. I want to use Angular 2's dependency injection to handle the data so that the data persist after the component is destroyed. From my understanding I should create a dependency injection service and `provide` it at a parent component. However, the data structure is not fixed, can I still use the service method? How to define the `Injectable` class?

Comment: if you can't define data type, use `any`.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html